# Shutdown of Debian 12 stops until switching to virtual console 7

Tags: linux, debian, shutdown

I installed Debian 12 (Bookworm) on a laptop (Acer Aspire 5). It is the only OS on the laptop and it was a fresh install.

Everything works fine, but when I try do power off the laptop, KDE is closed and I see all the text on the first virtual console, without any progress. The computer just keeps running.

Only when I switch to the virtual console 7 (`Alt`+`F7`) does the shutdown continue normally (with the normal shutdown log messages filling the screen before finally turing the laptop off.

Switching to any other virtual console just shows a blank black screen.

Answer (score 0):

This only happens when using Wayland (which is used by default since Debian Bookworm). After switching back to Plasma on X11 the shutdown behaves normally.